# Percentage not in order

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is my code to generate a horizontal bar chart. The percentage are not in order. I would like percentage from 0 to 100%.

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Site_name) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = sum(Race %in% "Missing"), perc = paste0(round(n/n()*100),"%")) %>%
ggplot(aes(Site_name, perc)) + geom_col(position = 'dodge', fill = "#0000FF", stat="identity") + 
         coord_flip() + geom_text(aes(label=perc), vjust=0, color="black",
            position = position_dodge(0.9), size=3.5)
```

The graph that is generated is below. But I want percentage axis in increase order from 0 to 100.

[image]

Comment: adjus the text with `vjust`  and `hjust` in `geom_text`.

Comment: ```perc``` is a factor string in your dataset and not a number. I would suggest to provide the value as numeric/integer and then plot it.

Comment: @maarvd  Ok got it. But how do I do it within this code?

Comment: ```perc = paste0(round(n/n()*100),"%"))``` to ```perc = round(n/n()*100)```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `dplyr::arrange`. [Documentation here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html)

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Site_name) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n = sum(Race %in% "Missing"), perc = round(n/n()*100)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(perc) %>%
ggplot(aes(Site_name, perc)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge', fill = "#0000FF", stat="identity") + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(
    aes(label=perc), 
    vjust=0, 
    color="black",
    position = position_dodge(0.9), 
    size=3.5
  )
```

Comment: Yes thats what I was looking for. Instead of this I used "as.numeric(sub("%", "", df1$perc)"